# Why do I get an exception when using Laravel redis cluster?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to configure my Laravel apllication to accept multiple redis nodes but I get an exception:

```
exception: "Predis\Response\ServerException"
file: "/home/vagrant/code/gryphon-laravel/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php"
line: 370
message: "MOVED 9576 10.225.25.33:6380"
```

**Code that generates the Exception:**

`$user = Redis::get('anything');`

**.env**

```
REDIS_CLUSTER=redis
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
```

**Config: database.php**

```
[...]
'redis' => [
        'cluster' => true,
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
        'clusters' => [
            'first' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => 0,
                ]
            ],
            'second'=> [
                [
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_2', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT_2', 6379),
                    'database' => 0,
                ]
            ],
            'third'=> [
                [
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_3', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT_3', 6379),
                    'database' => 0,
                ],
            ]
        ],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
            'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_',
            'parameters' => [
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            ],
        ],
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ]
    ],
[...]
```

I have searched and searched but have found nothing...

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redis) on this side is a bit vague :

> If your application is utilizing a cluster of Redis servers, you
>   should define these clusters within a clusters key of your Redis
>   configuration:
>
> ```
> 'redis' => [
>
> 'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
>
> 'clusters' => [
>     'default' => [
>         [
>             'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
>             'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
>             'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
>             'database' => 0,
>         ],
>     ],
> ],
> ```
>
> ],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predis has been abandoned by the package's original author and may be removed from Laravel in a future release.

So, I recommend to install php-ext phpredis

.env:

```
REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
```

Comment: Switching to phpredis and making multiple changes somehow fixed the issue.

Comment: @ka_lin I am having the same issue, I am using phpredis as client and my database configuration for redis looks like this

```'redis' => [

'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

'clusters' => [
    'default' => [
        [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
],```

I am using AWS Elasticache redis with cluster mode, Can you share the changes you made in the database.php?

Comment: `'redis'=>['cluster'=>true,'client'=>env('R_CLIENT','predis'),'clusters'=>['default'=>[['host'=>env('R_H1','localhost'),'port'=>env('R_P',6379)],['host'=>env('R_H2','localhost'),'port'=>env('R_P2',6379)],['host'=>env('R_H3','localhost'),'port'=>env('R_P3',6379)]]],'options'=>['cluster'=>env('R_CLUSTER','redis'),'prefix'=>env('MIX_PREFIX','la_db_'),'parameters'=>['password'=>env('R_PW')],],'default'=>['host'=>env('R_HOST','127.0.0.1'),'port'=>env('R_PORT',6379),'password'=>env('R_PW',null)],'cache'=>'host'=>env('R_HOST','127.0.0.1'),'port'=>env('R_PORT',6379),'database'=>env('R_CACHE_DB',1)]]`

Comment: @Akki Tried my best to minify the config

Comment: @ka_lin thanks a lot, I did figure this out yesterday, unfortunately, [horizon does not support Cluster Redis](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/274#issuecomment-457218217) for queues which kinda defeated my goal for setting up a cluster. But thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

File config/database.php

```
$redisConnStr = env('REDIS_CONNECTION', '127.0.0.1:6379');

$redis = [
    'client' => 'predis',
];

$redisConnections = explode(',', $redisConnStr);
if (count($redisConnections) === 1) {

    $params = explode(':', $redisConnections[0]);

    $redis = array_merge(
        $redis,
        [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

            'default' => [
                'host'     => $params[0] ?? '127.0.0.1',
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port'     => (int)($params[1] ?? 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
            ]
        ]
    );
}
else {
    $redisCacheCluster = [];

    foreach ($redisConnections as $conn){
        $params = explode(':', $conn);
        $redisCacheCluster[] = [
            'host'     => $params[0] ?? '127.0.0.1',
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => (int)($params[1] ?? 6379),
        ];
    }

    $redis             = array_merge(
        $redis,
        [
            'options'  => ['cluster' => 'redis'],
            'clusters' => [
                'default' => $redisCacheCluster,
            ]
        ]
    );
}

'redis' => $redis,
```

File config/cache.php

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],
```

File .env

```
REDIS_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1:6379, //all ips redis clusters
```

Comment: Basically this would mean that each node should be defined in `clusters.default`, unfortunately I get the same error